# Animate collapse and expand of toolbar - TabbedActivity

Tags: android, listview, toolbar

I'm trying to create an activity which has a toolbar and tabs.

I have in each tab a list view, I want that when i'm scrolling down or up the toolbar will collapse or expand. I want that the toolbar will be hidden or shown but the tabs that will be always shown.

I want something like this:

[image]

I tried too look for in the internet and found this library:
https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

The problem is that I havn't succeeded to use it in my application.

This is the layout of my acticity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context="subtitlesinc.subtitlegetter.TabbedActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

I'm not sure I need CoordinatorLayout - Do I need to replace it?

This is the code of the fragment I want that will collapse and expand the toolbar:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

private View mHeaderView;
private View mToolbarView;
private ObservableRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private int mBaseTranslationY;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.moviesList);

    MoviesArrayAdapter adapter = MoviesArrayAdapter.getInstance(TabbedActivity.getMainActivity(), R.layout.movie_layout, FileHandler.getInstance().getMoviesPaths());

    ListViewListener.initializeListener(TabbedActivity.getMainActivity());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewListener());

    return (rootView);
}
```

}

Can someone help me to figure out what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include a 3rd party library to make this happen. CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout support this behavior.

The Design Support Library sample project Cheesesquare implements this pattern. You can see the relevant XML file here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

I believe you just need to replace the `ViewPager` in your sample layout file with a `RecyclerView` to make this work correctly. Be sure to also have the `layout_behavior` set up on your `RecyclerView` (which is already in your sample XML).